# Interpreting a text character copied from a website and its format

Tags: windows, unicode, character-encoding, character, ascii

I'm curious as to how this works from a low-level point of view.

I understand that computers deal with text characters using Ascii code, or unicode.

For example, just now I copied a '€' character symbol from a website to put in an email because the character is not on my keyboard.

How does Windows store this character? as a unique integer identifying this character? When I paste this character into an email or word document, even it preserves its text format.

How does the email editor or word application know how to translate what I copied with exact same format? What if where I copied the character from, it was using its own special type of character-encoding, would it translate to the wrong character then when I pasted it in an email.

Comment: 1) forget about ascii - it should be dead and buried. 2) to type the € on a Windows machine, it is `AltGr 4` the AltGr is to the right of a spacebar.

Comment: @Dragonthoughts i'm not asking how to type it from the keyboard. I am interested to know what goes on behind the scenes when I copy and paste a character the way I did. Thanks

Comment: Windows will copy the character(s) transcode them to store them in a Unicode format - probably UTF-16. When you paste, the characters, it will insert them into the paste buffer as Unicode code-points. In Windows, what you type is also converted into Unicode code points.

Comment: Other metadata, about formatting is retained in the copy buffers for applications that can use it. If they can't, e.g. Notepad then the plain text form is requested.

Comment: @Dragonthoughts ok thanks for that

Comment: The Windows clipboard only knows about 2 plain-text formats natively - ANSI and Unicode (UTF-16). When you copy text from somewhere, the app being copied from stores the text in one of those formats (preferably UTF-16).  When the text gets pasted later, the receiving app converts the text from that stored format to whatever format it wants. An app can query which format(s) are currently on the clipboard and retrieve them as needed.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: that looks like a complete answer!